# Java Event Sourcing/DDD framework not polluting domain layer

Tags: java, frameworks, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I am looking for a Java framework/library to perform event sourcing such that my domain modules/layers are not polluted by it or any other framework but that allows me to publish domain events from my aggregates.

I looked at [Axon](http://axonframework.org) documentation but it works using inheritance over Aggregates and DomainEvents that is not really satisfying.

I attempted to build my own mini-framework based on spring injection and static publishing from aggregates but I am concerned about performance and scalability, therefore I would rather use a bulletproof framework.

Comment: For what it is worth, most of the heavyweights in the DDD/ES space are very anti framework.

Comment: I also don't like base types.  Currently I like returning the events immediately from the command methods.  In this way whatever mechanism you use also has access to the events.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregates are just recording the new change events. They aren't publishing the events themselves so there is nothing complicated there that would require a framework. Events are generally published by the event store through a collaborating service, but you can also do it elsewhere in the processing pipeline (e.g. repository).

Still, I'd recommend you to have an `AggregateRoot` layer supertype. Have a look at Greg Young's [m-r](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/Domain.cs).

Answer (score 0):

[Occurrent](https://occurrent.org) is an event sourcing library for the JVM that is built to provide a clean separation between domain model and infrastructure components.

I.e. you can write your domain model in any way you find fit, without any dependencies to Occurrent, or any other library. You use Occurrent to store events and subscribe to event store changes.